# Is there a way to append multiple items of the same value to a list from a dictionary without using another for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of 'event' names (key) and multiplicities (value) for distributions.  I want to convert this dictionary into a list to reduce run time to use binary search.  I do not want to add another for loop as I feel like that will increase my run time.

I have tried looping through my dictionary and appending while multiplying the key by value but that only gives me the key*value instead of a number of keys that is the value number.

mydict = {'a':5, 'b':7, 'c':10, 'd':2}
myrichard = []

for x,y in mydict.items():
    myrichard.append(x * y)

I would want to have the output of ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'] but I get the output of ['aaaaa', 'bbbbbbb', 'cccccccccc', 'dd'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `list.extend` method.

```
>>> mydict = {'a':5, 'b':7, 'c':10, 'd':2}
>>> myrichard = []
>>> for x,y in mydict.items():
...     myrichard.extend(x * y)
...
>>> myrichard
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
```